# Is it possible to specify an assembly scoped using directive?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, using

I have a couple of `string` extension methods in an assembly `A`. In assembly `B`, i'm not able to use these extension methods unless I add an `using A` directive in each of the .cs files in assembly `B`.
Is there a way, in the `B` assembly project configuration to specify a using for the entire assembly? similar to c++ `stdafx.h`

Thanks

Comment: No, every source-code-file needs its own `usings` to access members and types from other namespaces. There´s no global header to publish all the references as in C++, at least not in this sense. This makes it easier to see where a member is defined as you directly see which dependencies exist for a given file.

Comment: I was going to mention VB's project imports (see @Damien's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44287428/2226988)). I delete them all and, in each file, put just the Imports directives needed by that file. A good IDE helps with the housekeeping and the code says what it means.

Comment: @Tom, I agree, but the IDE won't detect in which assembly your extension method is like it does with classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using` includes a *namespace*, not an assembly. It's not necessary for a namespace to have the same name as its assembly (even if it is a common convention).

If it's natural for you to want to include your string extensions across all of your assemblies because they represent common functionality, then just put them in a top-level namespace, e.g. `MyCompanyName.MyApplication`. These are then in scope from any other class in the same or a child namespace.

(This does assume that all your namespaces follow the common practice of descending from a common root e.g. `MyCompanyName...`.)

Comment: That's a grrrreeat solution. I didnt tought that the top level namespace (ex. `MyCompanyName` in `MyCompanyName.MyApplication`) would defacto be included. Thanks!

Comment: It's good to clarify assembly vs namespace but, I think you stated it backward: It's a convention for an assembly to have _some_ type with a namespace that shares a root name with the assembly. (It's also a convention to name the assembly's manifest file (e.g., DLL) after the assembly. That's why the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) have all that detail when describing a type.)

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes, you're right. I can't quite think how to get that across succinctly, but feel free to edit if you think you can.

Comment: P.S. One antipattern I often see is putting common code in a namespace called `MyCompanyName.MyApplication.Common`. This makes it only common to the `Common` namespace without a `using` directive! If it's common, move it up.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such feature currently.

A useful way to see what features are supported at the assembly/project level is to look at the help for the command line compilers.

Visual Basic uses `Import` statements in the same way as C# has `using` directives, and has the concept of [Project Imports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w4tctcf.aspx). And, indeed, when we look at the output of `vbc /?`, we can see:

```
                                  - LANGUAGE -

/define:<symbol_list>             Declare global conditional compilation
                                  symbol(s). symbol_list:name=value,...
                                  (Short form: /d)
/imports:<import_list>            Declare global Imports for namespaces in
                                  referenced metadata files.
                                  import_list:namespace,...
/langversion:<number>             Specify language version:
                                  9|9.0|10|10.0|11|11.0|12|12.0|14|14.0
/optionexplicit[+|-]              Require explicit declaration of variables.
/optioninfer[+|-]                 Allow type inference of variables.
/rootnamespace:<string>           Specifies the root Namespace for all type
                                  declarations.
/optionstrict[+|-]                Enforce strict language semantics.
/optionstrict:custom              Warn when strict language semantics are not
                                  respected.
/optioncompare:binary             Specifies binary-style string comparisons.
                                  This is the default.
/optioncompare:text               Specifies text-style string comparisons.
```

And we can see that there is the `/imports` option.

If we look at the equivalent section of `csc /?`, we see:

```
                        - LANGUAGE -
 /checked[+|-]                 Generate overflow checks
 /unsafe[+|-]                  Allow 'unsafe' code
 /define:<symbol list>         Define conditional compilation symbol(s) (Short
                               form: /d)
 /langversion:<string>         Specify language version mode: ISO-1, ISO-2, 3,
                               4, 5, 6, or Default
```

And we can see that there's no equivalent `/using`/`/usings`. From this, we can deduce that there's no way to inform the C# compiler of a set of `using` directives to apply to every file whilst compiling an assembly.

Comment: It's a strange thing that they included the feature in VB but not in c#. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`using` imports a namespace into current context to avoid referencing classes and other other constructs by their fully qualified name.

You could (but a bad idea) to put all constructs in one namespace in assembly B, and thus you would need only one `using`.  Bad idea is because of poor code organization, etc.

Depending what your assembly B contains, your string extension functions could probably be put in the same namespace (while other stuff like models be in separate one).  That seems for a decent organization.

And note that all these extension functions can be in separate .cs files, and still be in the same namespace, thus requiring one `using` declaration to import them all.

E.g.

## ExtensionA.cs

```
namespace AssemblyB.Strings.Extensions
{
    public static string ExtensionA(this string source, ...) {...}
}
```

## ExtensionB.cs

```
namespace AssemblyB.Strings.Extensions
{
    public static string ExtensionB(this string source, ...) {...}
}
```

## ExtensionC.cs

```
namespace AssemblyB.Strings.Extensions
{
    public static string ExtensionC(this string source, ...) {...}
}
```

## AssemblyA.cs

```
using AssemblyBStrings.Extensions;

    ...
    var b = "Hello World".ExtensionA().ExtensionB().ExtensionC();
```

Comment: In fact, my extensions are already in the same assembly and namespace. What  I'm trying to eliminate is the need to add  the `using` directive to each .cs file I'm developping as I am aware of these extensions, but not necessarily all my coworkers

Comment: As the answer by Damien suggests, I don't believe there is such a feature.  That said, RedGate's ReSharper aids in that and automatically puts usings.  So if this is a question of developer convenience, it'll do it for you, for a $, of course.